Email received in Shared mailbox Power automate trigger : Causing error
I am working on an reqquirement where I need to track received mails on an mailbox .
My flow was running just fine with personal mailboxes but stops working since I am trying fit into Shared mailbox trigger
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Item 'DEMO_ITEM_ID_1' doesn't belong to the targeted mailbox 'DEMO_MAILBOX_ID'.\r\nclientRequestId: demo-client-request-id\r\nserviceRequestId: demo-service-request-id",
  "error": {
    "message": "Item 'DEMO_ITEM_ID_1' doesn't belong to the targeted mailbox 'DEMO_MAILBOX_ID'.",
    "code": "ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId",
    "originalMessage": "Item 'DEMO_ITEM_ID_1' doesn't belong to the targeted mailbox 'DEMO_MAILBOX_ID'."
  },
  "source": "office365-ase.azconn-ase-001.p.azurewebsites.net"
}

Any solutions or walkthroughs would be greatly appreciated.
